# Load images from a jar file

Tags: java

I have an application that works perfectly from the Netbeans IDE, but when run from the jar file in the dist directory does not load the necessary images.

I have spent 1 1/2 days reading this and other forums, trying to find an answer, but I can't get the jar images to work.

Here he is an extract from my code:

```
String str = t.getText() + "100.gif";
Image img = null;

if (t != HIDDEN)
{
    ClassLoader cldr = Terrain.class.getClassLoader();
    URL url = cldr.getResource("fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);

    if (url == null)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no good");

    img = ImageIO.read(url);
    t.setImage(img);
}
```

I have tried many combinations of relative path, including "images/", "/images/", etc. The images are in the jar file:

```
 fantasyhexwar/Images/plains100.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/quarry60.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/ram80.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/save map40.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/scout80.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/settler80.gif
 fantasyhexwar/Images/ship80.gif
```

etc...

I know I am missing something fundamental, but I'm not sure what. My suspicion is that it is something to do with the manifest file or possibly class path.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction...

EDIT:
The problem seems to be that

```
URL url = Terrain.class.getResource("/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);
```

returns null. The images are definitely in the JAR, and in desperation I have also tried all possible relative paths, with code like this:

```
ClassLoader cldr = Terrain.class.getClassLoader();
URL url = Terrain.class.getResource("/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("/fantasyhexwar/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("fantasyhexwar/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("/Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("Images/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource("/" + str);
if (url == null)
    url = cldr.getResource(str);
if (url == null)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no good");
```

But none of it works when executing directly from the JAR...

When I try to run from the command line, I get:

> java -cp .;FantasyHexWar.jar FantasyHexWarApp

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FantasyHexWarApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FantasyHexWarApp
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: FantasyHexWarApp.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: fantasyhexwar is the name of you jar??

Comment: Are the code and the images in separate JAR files, or are they in the same JAR file? Have you checked the JAR file to ensure that your resources are being included?

Comment: does it work from the command line but without the jar?

Comment: code and images are in the same JAR file. Yes I have checked that the images are included

Comment: I can't get it to work from the command line, so I presume it could be a class path issue

Comment: The usage looks correct. Are there multiple class loaders involved?

Comment: no. I have also tried and failed to get URL url = Terrain.class.getResource("/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str); to work, but it returns a null URL. What reason could there be for returning a null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was a little careless with my filenames. For example one file was called "save map.png", but the application was looking for "Save Map.png".

This worked fine when loading files from the drive, but when turned into a URL and loaded directly from the jar, it made all the difference.

Therefore, it seems that resource file names in a jar are **case-sensitive**.

Answer (score 2):

If the images are in the jar file, under *fantasyhexwar/Images/*.*,

```
Image image = getToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fantasyhexwar/Images/plains100.gif"));
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a detailed explanation of how this works.

Comment: @Mark Keen, the tutorial is about loading icons. It shows how you might structure your jar file to contain class and image file. In not one of the examples does it start with "fantasyhexwar". All the example show the URL as starting with your directory name. The tutorial also shows how  you can specify the class path from the command line.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually a helpful page. I have been looking at a earlier today also. The trouble is, in my case getClass().getResource(path);  returns a null URL, even though I am convinced that the path is correct, and the image is in the JAR. I have even tried to run it from the command line using the given commands. I can only think that perhaps the manifest information in my JAR is not set up correctly - it is currently also generated by the Netneans IDE...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution came to me reading the opinions about getToolkit() function. In my case I am building a desktop application, and the function getToolkit() is not avalaible for me. Instead  I need to use this code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path));
```

The program now functions in and out the Netbeans Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth giving this a shot.

```
Image theImage = getToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image"))
```

Comment: The problem is getResource("/fantasyhexwar/Images/" + str") returns a null URL even though the gif is in there

Comment: In the java doc, it says getResource() returns `A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found`. My guess is either the path is wrong or the file is not in there. Can you extract your jar and double check the path and that the file is indeed in there?

Comment: Just extracted them ok, and the images were in the fantasyhexwar/Images directory as expected. Could it be an  issue with a security policy not giving permission to access the images in the JAR? The thing is I can easily make it work with the images outside the JAR, so I may have to distribute it like that. I just wish I knew what the problem was...

Comment: Its possible, but i'm still leaning towards it not being able to find them for some reason. Did you try the code I posted to get the resource? Did it throw an exception or give you a null image?

Comment: Well I am calling it from a static method, so I had to modify it to Terrain.class.getResource("/path/to/image"). Tomorrow I will try shifting the code to another location as a test. Also I wonder if I am calling it too soon - Terrain.loadTerrainImages();      Building.loadBuildingImages(); TroopType.loadTroopImages(); are all called after component initialisation in the view constructor. However this isn't a problem if the images aren't in a JAR.

Comment: Interesting issue. Im heading out for the day, but let me know how your tests go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've decided to leave this issue for now. Simply removing my images from the JAR and putting them into a separate Images folder in the dist works for the time being. Maybe I will investigate again when I come to properly release my application. In the meantime, I have too much coding to do, to spend any more time on this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with loading images from jar. The exception you get says:-

```
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: FantasyHexWarApp. Program will exit.
```

That means, `FantasyHexWarApp` main class is missing from the jar. Fix that and it should work just fine. :)

Comment: Yes, but it's not. In fact it works if I disable loading the images. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this to display images from .jar files

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/Springz3.png");
```